# Checking multiple prerequisite for a subject

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, phpmyadmin

My friend told me that i need to set my prerequisite id as varchar and store the prerequisite separated by comma ?

This is what i have now. 
i manage to get and check prerequisite id base on the subject id 
but i can only store and check one prerequisite because i store it as integer but now i change it to varchar and seperated the other prerequisite by comma. See my database

[image]

This is all i have right now.
This code work for only one prerequiste.

```
 Private Sub EnrollStudent(ByVal StudentID As Integer, ByVal SubjectID As Integer)
    '**CHECKING IF SUBJECT HAS A PREREQUISITE
    Dim Prerequisite As Integer
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select pre_id from subject  where subject_id = @subject_id", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@subject_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = SubjectID
            cn.Open()
            Prerequisite = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    '**ANSWER = NO / NO PREREQUISITE ? DO THIS -> CALL THE INSERTENROLLMENT FUNCTION 
    If Prerequisite = 0 Then
        InsertEnrollment(StudentID, SubjectID, lbl_As_SchoolYear.Text)
        Return
    End If

    '**ANSWER = YES / THERE IS A PREREQUISITE
    '**CHECKING IF THE SUBJECT IS PASSED

    '**CHECKING FOR INC GRADES SINCE INC IS STRING
    Dim PassingGradeStr As String
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select grade FROM student_subject WHERE sub_id =@sub_id AND student_id =@student_id", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sub_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Prerequisite
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@student_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = StudentID
            cn.Open()
            PassingGradeStr = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using

    '**CHECKING IF THE GRADE IS INC / IF INC THEN EXIT SUB
    If PassingGradeStr = "INC" Then
        MessageBox.Show("GRADE STILL INC")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '**PASSING GRADE IS NOT INC / SO GRADE MUST BE INTEGER

    Dim PassingGrade As Integer
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select Grade From student_subject Where sub_id = @sub_id And student_id = @student_id", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sub_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Prerequisite
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@student_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = StudentID
            cn.Open()
            PassingGrade = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using

    '**CHECKING IF THE GRADE IS GREATER THAN 0 / IF TRUE THEN IT IS PASSED / CALL INSERTENROLLMENT FUNCTION
    If PassingGrade > 0 Then
        If PassingGrade = 4 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Prerequisite Subject is 4")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If PassingGrade = 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Prerequisite Subject is Failed")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        InsertEnrollment(StudentID, SubjectID, lbl_As_SchoolYear.Text)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Student cannot enroll because of prerequisite.")
    End If
End Sub
```

I manage to do it by doing one of the comment suggestion. by adding another column for prerequisite., I know this is not really efficient way to do this so any suggestion i will gladly try it. Thanks.

I'll be posting what i did to fix mine anyway.
**UPDATE:**
[image]

A bit messed up cause i duplicate all the code i have to check
for the another column that i add.

```
  '**CHECKING IF SUBJECT HAS A PREREQUISITE
    Dim Prerequisite As Integer
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select pre_id from subject  where subject_id = @subject_id", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@subject_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = SubjectID
            cn.Open()
            Prerequisite = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    '**ANSWER = NO / NO PREREQUISITE ? DO THIS -> CALL THE INSERTENROLLMENT FUNCTION 


    Dim Prerequisite2 As Integer
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select pre_id2 from subject  where subject_id = @subject_id", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@subject_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = SubjectID
            cn.Open()
            Prerequisite2 = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using



    If Prerequisite = 0 Then
        InsertEnrollment(StudentID, SubjectID, lbl_As_SchoolYear.Text)
        Return
    End If


    If Prerequisite2 = 0 Then
        InsertEnrollment(StudentID, SubjectID, lbl_As_SchoolYear.Text)
        Return
    End If




    '**ANSWER = YES / THERE IS A PREREQUISITE
    '**CHECKING IF THE SUBJECT IS PASSED

    '**CHECKING FOR INC GRADES SINCE INC IS STRING
    Dim PassingGradeStr As String
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select grade FROM student_subject WHERE sub_id =@sub_id AND student_id =@student_id", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sub_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Prerequisite
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@student_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = StudentID
            cn.Open()
            PassingGradeStr = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using


    Dim PassingGradeStr2 As String
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select grade FROM student_subject WHERE sub_id =@sub_id AND student_id =@student_id", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sub_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Prerequisite2
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@student_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = StudentID
            cn.Open()
            PassingGradeStr2 = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using






    '**CHECKING IF THE GRADE IS INC / IF INC THEN EXIT SUB
    If PassingGradeStr = "INC" Then
        MessageBox.Show("GRADE STILL INC")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If PassingGradeStr2 = "INC" Then
        MessageBox.Show("GRADE STILL INC")
        Exit Sub
    End If



    '**PASSING GRADE IS NOT INC / SO GRADE MUST BE INTEGER

    Dim PassingGrade As Integer
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select Grade From student_subject Where sub_id = @sub_id And student_id = @student_id", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sub_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Prerequisite
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@student_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = StudentID
            cn.Open()
            PassingGrade = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using


    Dim PassingGrade2 As Integer
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select Grade From student_subject Where sub_id = @sub_id And student_id = @student_id", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sub_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Prerequisite2
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@student_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = StudentID
            cn.Open()
            PassingGrade2 = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using




    '**CHECKING IF THE GRADE IS GREATER THAN 0 / IF TRUE THEN IT IS PASSED / CALL INSERTENROLLMENT FUNCTION
    If PassingGrade > 0 And PassingGrade2 > 0 Then
        If PassingGrade = 4 Or PassingGrade2 = 4 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Prerequisite Subject is 4")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If PassingGrade = 5 Or PassingGrade2 = 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Prerequisite Subject is Failed")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        InsertEnrollment(StudentID, SubjectID, lbl_As_SchoolYear.Text)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Student cannot enroll because of prerequisite.")
    End If
```

Comment: If pre_id can have more than 1 value per row, you should make another table with that data.

Comment: Why don't you read it as a string from the database, than split the string with commas and then parse each integer value with something like `CInt` or `Integer.Parse`.

Comment: *"My friend told me that i need to set my prerequisite id as varchar and store the prerequisite separated by comma ?"* that is a sin in databases i advice you to read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad),,

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras Thank you i can't mark you comment as answer. But thank you. I actually misread the table as column and make a column instead haha. but that fixed it anyway thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help you, have a nice day! :-)

Comment: Your update is very poor database design. Your school should have a prerequisite for this course that deals with database design.